# Adobe Illustrator - how to prevent the "Eraser Tool" from changing the target brushes' size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

I am running **Adobe Illustrator 2014**, Release 2014.0.0 18.0.0 (x64).

I'm using a custom brush with these settings:
[image: Brush options]

Whenever I draw a (pressure sensitive) line using my Wacom Intuos Pen & Touch and then erase a part of that line using the **Eraser Tool (SHIFT + E)**, the remaining parts of that line will become way thicker, almost as if I never used pressure senitivity drawing that line and just drew it using the same brush and my mouse.

Here is an example of the line before and after using the eraser tool on it:
[image: Example lines]

How do I set it up so it does not change the thickness when I remove parts of the line using the Eraser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a erasor cuts though a stroke it separates it into 2 different paths. It then causes it to re-apply the brush changing the pressure.

To stop this go to `Object` and press `Expand Appearance`

[Explanation Image http://blogs.adobe.com/infiniteresolution/Eraser_Brush.jpg](http://blogs.adobe.com/infiniteresolution/Eraser_Brush.jpg)

Comment: Hi.. it's a workaround, but the brush becomes a shape. So wherever you erase, the segment "endpoint" becomes flat -- the original brush shape isn't retained.
//

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Blob brush tool using calligraphic pens. 
This will not draw a line with different stroke size properties, but it will create a shape path, according to the line you have just created. 
Basically it does the same as expand appearance, but every time you draw a line and on every line you have drawn that is not locked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **Path Eraser Tool** instead.
However, you need to select your target line every time.

(use a combo of **Direct Selection Tool** (*alt/opt+select*) with **Path Eraser Tool**)

I found the answer here:
Eraser brush changes lines from straight to curved
https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/eraser-brush-changes-lines-from-straight-to-curved/td-p/8798382?page=1

(archived page:

//
https://archive.is/nby9O

or //
https://web.archive.org/web/20200206104213/https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/eraser-brush-changes-lines-from-straight-to-curved/td-p/8798382?page=1
)